# How to simplify $F(w)=wCw^T+12ww^T \leftrightarrow F(w)=w(C+12I)w^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I cannot figure out how to simplify $F(w)=wCw^T+12ww^T$ to $F(w)=w(C+12I)w^T$

where $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $w$ is a $1\times n$ vector and $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $Iw^T = w^T$, so $ww^T = wIw^T$.

Then,

$$w C w^T + 12ww^T = w C w^T + 12wIw^T  = w(C w^T + 12Iw^T) =  w(C + 12I)w^T,$$

by basic distributive properties of matrix multiplication.

Comment: thank you, I forgot matrices and vectors can be factored out like regular numbers.

Comment: You're welcome. Yep, a lot (but not all) of algebraic properties of matrices are just like numbers.